# Regex matching text NOT containing ANY of the (multiple) words on a given list

Tags: c#, regex

In [this answer], there's an example on how to **exclude** a certain word from the search. I'm using it to filter out CSS, JS and GIF calls in the network tab of Chrome.

```
^((?!badword).)*$
```

When I [play with different combinations](https://www.regextester.com/15) to exclude **both** the string *css* and *gif*, I get results that either exclude everything or include everything.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations using the pipe operator to mimic the concept of OR. Neither work and I'm out of ideas.

How should I reason to get it working? It was surprisingly hard to find an example that excluded multiple words.

Comment: Do you mean using a negative lookahead with an alternation? `^(?!.*\.(?:gif|css|js)).*$` https://regex101.com/r/yUlOCf/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I fear that I'm asking wrong question. The example of yours is great and does precisely what I described. When I pasted it in the filter box in Chrome on the network tab to remove the calls that targeted those file extensions, I got nothing left in the list, though.

Comment: Did you try putting it between forward slashes? `/^(?!.*\.(?:gif|css|js)).*$/`

Comment: @Thefourthbird What a silly mistake. You're perfectly right. This works just as expected: `/^(?!.*\.(?:gif|css|js)).*$/` but I noticed that when I tried to set a dot as additional condition, just in case, the result was that the match failed. I tried to escape the dot like this: `/^(?!.*\.(?:\.gif|\.css|\.js)).*$/` and to have it verbatim like this: `/^(?!.*\.(?:[.]gif|[.]css|[.]js)).*$/`. I suspect it's due to the negative look-ahead that I hardly understand. Got a hint for that too or should I ask a new question?

Comment: In the pattern `/^(?!.*\.(?:gif|css|js)).*$/` the dot is already part of the condition in this part `\.(?:gif|css|js)` which means match a dot followed by any of the options which are listed using an `|` alternation. If you add a dot as you tried you are matching 2 dots like `..gif`.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I didn't notice that, despite looking. I believe it's time to drop the keyboard and start hugging a pillow. At any rate - you might want to post your comments as an answer to be accepted. You've been of great help. Thank you.